# Router-Outlet not working first time

Tags: angular, routes

In my application I have the following template in app.component.ts and it has to show the menu and the rendered view. When path is empty it has to redirect to Dashbard. For the first time the router-outlet is not working. But when I reload the page it appears. Any ideas?

template:

```
<nav>
  <ul>                          
      <li *ngFor='let route of routes'>
        <a [routerLink]="['/' + route.path]" (click)="changeMenuActivation(route.path)">{{route.name}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Please format you code to be more readable.

Comment: How did you define the routes?

Comment: the first time this error is thrown

Comment: :49863/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3070 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Index.html'
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Index.html'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:49863/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.

Comment: Like Tudor asked, could you post your route definitions as well :)

Comment: I have mapped the Project one more time and now it works. Thanks